# Laravel 5: Extend delete() on model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I'm using L5.3.31 and have the following models:

Addon

Image

Relationship:

```
// Addon.php
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}

// Image.php
public function addon()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Addon');
}
```

I now want to extend the `delete()` method to delete some images that are saved on the file system when deleting an image object. To my understand, in order to do this I need to extend the `delete()` method on the Image model. Now, on my image model, if I try to do this:

```
public function delete()
{
    dd('triggered');
    parent::delete();
}
```

I expect it to die and dump `triggered`. But nothing happens, object(s) gets deleted just like before. That tells me the above block of code doesn't get executed when deleting, right?

I also tried the same thing on the Addon model, same result. In the end, what I want to accomplish is this, when I do

`$addon->images()->delete();` I want laravel to delete files representing each image object. In addition if I do `$addon->images()->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();` I want to delete the images files for the given id alongside the object.

Btw, I don't know if this is important or not, but I have set the relationshipt to delete on cascade, so if I do `$addon->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();` it also deletes its related image objects.

Comment: You're better off using a [listener/observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between

`$addon->images()->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();`

and

`$addon->images()->find(11)->delete();`

The first one is on query builder level (this does not trigger the deleting/deleted events on the model).

The second one is on model level (this does trigger the deleting/deleted events on the model).
Check this documentation on events in Laravel 5.4

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

You can add observer to catch the deleting event and do what you want
and there is an issue opened and closed on Laravel about the same thing
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: Welcome @ArtemiosAntonioBalbach