# Laravel 6.x relation set default value on delete on relationship partner

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have the following two models:

`stockItem`. `category`

`stockItem` can have one `category` and `category` can have many `stockItem`.

In`category` there is alway the first category with the id of 1. It can not be deleted.

Now if `category` with id of 2 gets deleted, all `stockItem` with the relation to the second `category` should be updated to the first `category`.

Is ORM capable of that or do I need to write an own delete function? If so how do I overwrite the delete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to go for this but you must make some modifications.

Laravel has `onDelete` actions when running migrations. For your problem i think suitable is:

```
->onDelete('set null');
```

In order to have this work you will have to change your foreign key (`categoryId`) to be nullable.

Having done that when you delete a category then all the relations that this category had will be set their field to null, meaning they will belong to `category1` which can never be deleted.

This is the approach to do it with pure migrations and this is the closest you can get. That way you will know that when categoryId is null or 1 this stockitem belongs to category1 or was transferred to it cause another category was deleted.

If you really need the id to be 1 then you should use either a helper class that you build yourself, or [Laravel Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#observers).

Comment: The laravel observers, do they trigger on every delete function call? I read that there are two different ones. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592437/laravel-5-extend-delete-on-model

Comment: They trigger on a model action, so yes you can build your logic to what you want to do when delete is triggered for this model.

Comment: Thanks, the Observer method is perfect for my use case!